# About tkinter entry, and the FocusOut/FocusIn

Tags: python, tkinter

I got the problem with FocusOut/FocusIn

I will show a part of my code below directly

```
win2 = tk.Tk()
win2.title("Bill")
entry0 = tk.Entry(win2, width=7)
entry0.insert(0, "(Auto)")
entry0.pack()
entry1 = tk.Entry(win2, width=7)
entry1.insert(0, "(Auto)")
entry1.pack()
entry2 = tk.Entry(win2, width=7)
entry2.insert(0, "(Auto)")
entry2.pack()
entryN = tk.Entry(win2, width=7)
entryN.insert(0, "(Auto)")
entryN.pack()
```

Beacuse of the "entry" will appears too many times, I would replaced it by 'N'.

And I doing something like this below:

```
def F1(e):
    x.delete(0, "end")
def F2(e):
    x.insert(0, "(Auto)")
list = [entry0, entry1, entry2] (Take three examples)
for x in list:
    x.bind("<FocusIn>", F1)
    x.bind("<FocusOut>", F2)
```

The purpose of the above is that when I select the input box, the box will be empty. And when I leave the box, the specific words will be filled in automatically.
Fortunately, this code is very successful, if there is only one "entry" box.

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work well with multiple "entries",
when I select the first input box, the first box did nothing and only the last "entry" responds,
only the last box is working when I In/Out.
Regardless of the number of "entries", only the last "entry" works.

I know there is another way is not run by list, and put them back to main part.
I tried, and it works as my purpose.
The real situation is that the full version has hundreds of such "entries",
I making them into a list not just only easy management, there are many similar situations later.
So if possible, do it with the list method first, unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

The `e` parameter passed to the function is shorthand for `event`. It is an object representing the event that triggered the callback. One of the attributes of the object is `widget`. You can use that instead of `x` in your function.

```
def F1(e):
    e.widget.delete(0, "end")
def F2(e):
    e.widget.insert(0, "(Auto)")
```

Comment: Thnak you very much.