# Removing focus for tkinter widgets with clicks outside the frame but within the window

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm a google learned hobbyist programmer for a while now. Gotta say thanks for Stack and everyone here.

working to create a modified Tkinter listbox where I want to bind or unbind an event based on the focus of the widget. Binding when the widget gets the focus is pretty straight forward with focusIn.

When the focus moves is also pretty easy with the focusOut. The trouble is when the widget is inside a frame or Canvas and the user clicks in dead space of the Frame or Canvas. There the focus doesn't move so the FocusOut event isn't fired. I am trying to make the widget self contained so I don't want the additional maintenance of adding a click event for each frame/canvas the modified widget is either in or adjacent to.

What my ultimate goal is to utilize the delete key to remove items from the modified listbox. The trouble is when the widget is apart of other Frames/Canvases where the user may click in dead space thinking the focus and either shifted or at least turned off and then hit delete. This would delete any item in the modified listbox in advertently.

Is there a way to detect a click event for all mouse clicks outside of the widget.

Here is a slimmed up version of the code.

Looking for a version where I would get a "Delete is Off by Focus Moving" when clicked in gray area inside (not the buttons but the frame dead space) of the window.

```
import tkinter

class Expanded_Listbox(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, Frm, **kw):
        super().__init__(Frm)
        Value=['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4']
        self.LstBx=tkinter.Listbox(self,exportselection=False,highlightcolor="#0000ff",**kw)
        self.LstBx.grid(row=0,column=0)
        for x in Value:
            print(x)
            self.LstBx.insert('end',x)

class Expanded_Listbox_WithEntry(Expanded_Listbox):
    def __init__(self, Frm, **kw):
        super().__init__(Frm,**kw)
        self.LstBx.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.EntBx=tkinter.Entry(self,width=self.LstBx['width']-5,state='disabled',background='gray')
        Btn=tkinter.Button(self,width=3,height=1,text='*')
        Btn.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.EntBx.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.LstBx["height"]=self.LstBx["height"]-1
        self.LstBx["selectmode"]="browse"
        self.LstBx['exportselection']=False

        self.LstBx.bind("<FocusIn>",self.Turn_On_Delete)
        self.LstBx.bind("<FocusOut>",self.Turn_Off_Delete)

    def Turn_On_Delete(self, event):
        # self.LstBx.bind("<Delete>",self.DelItm)
        print('Delete is On, by click')

    def Turn_Off_Delete(self, event):
        # self.LstBx.unbind("<Delete>")
        print('Delete is OFF by Focus Moving')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=tkinter.Tk()
    TmpFrame1=tkinter.Frame(root,width=150)
    TmpFrame1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    Item_List_Box=Expanded_Listbox_WithEntry(TmpFrame1,height=25, width=25)
    tkinter.Button(TmpFrame1,text="Here I am").grid(row=0,column=1)
    Item_List_Box.grid(row=0,column=0)
    outsideBtn=tkinter.Button(root,text='Outside button').grid(row=0,column=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Lots of googling and trying this and that and finally asking my first question here.

I've tried a bunch of different attempts but all would require adding several lines of code to elements outside of the main module.

I've boiled it down to either detecting the mouse click event everywhere then checking if the widget is below the mouse or finding the upper most window and looking under the mouse again.

I apprecaite you help in advance

Comment: I don't see a link

Comment: You can try binding `<Button-1>` on root window which all its children widgets will inherit the binding.

Comment: @Kyle Kraxberger. OOps! Sorry. Here is link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76411353/about-tkinter-entry-and-the-focusout-focusin

Comment: No that is the easy way effectively as shifting the focus is easy when widgets such as Entry automatically shifts the focus.

What I am looking for is a method that auto shifts the focus when clicking on widgets that don't auto accept focus like the body of a frame or canvas. 

In the example code above I want the focus to shift off the listbox if the user clicks on the grey area above both buttons similar to how the focus shift if the user click outside the window.